# Radix Sort (Why am I getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException line:43)

Tags: arrays, sorting, radix

I have given a time to this algorithm but still can't figure out where am I doing something wrong. Can anyone help me with my logic on "Radix Sort", if I am doing right with the following code then please help my figure out why am I getting the **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at line:arr[sortedIndex] = tempArray[j][k];**

```
    int[] arr = {3,10,50,137,90,139,40};
    int maxValue = arr[0], sortedIndex = 0, mode = 10, n = 1;

    // Displays unsorted array
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");

    // finds maximum digit
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] > maxValue){
            maxValue = arr[i];
        }
    }

    // Gets number of digits
    int maxDigits = (String.valueOf(maxValue)).length();

    for(int i = 0; i < maxDigits; i++){
        int[][] tempArray = new int[10][arr.length];

        // Transfers 1-D array value to 2-D array w.r.t baseIndex
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
            int modulus = arr[j] % mode;
            int baseIndex = modulus / n;

            for(int k = 0; k < tempArray[baseIndex].length; k++){
                if(tempArray[baseIndex][k] == 0){
                    tempArray[baseIndex][k] = arr[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Shifts partially sorted array to new array
        for(int j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < tempArray[j].length; k++){
                if(tempArray[j][k] > 0){
                    arr[sortedIndex] = tempArray[j][k];
                    sortedIndex++;
                }
            }
        }

        mode *= 10;
        n *= 10;
    }

    // Displays sorted array
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Is `arr` long enough?

Comment: What do you mean by long enough brother?

Comment: It needs to be able to hold the entire set of input data. Since you use the bounds of the source array it almost has to be the target array that isn't long enough for what `sortedIndex` grows to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the contents of tempArray before you attempt to shift partially sorted array to new array to see what it holds . arr[] can only hold 7 values. tempArray has more than 7 values greater than 0. Therefore, you are attempting to fill the arr[] with more than 7 numbers.

Comment: I had a hint from your comment and came to know that 'sortedIndex' was incremented continuously even after second time outer loop is executed which makes 'sortedIndex' greater than length of 'arr' the second time when value of tempArray is shifted to new array.